# when rotate how to dynamically change layout to avoid re-start activity

Tags: android, layout, orientation-changes

Having a layout which has horizontally side by side A and B parts when in landscape mode. Let's say A take 1/3 of the screen and B take other 2/3.
When rotate what is wanted is that the A keeps its original width but is changed to overlay on top of the B and B changes to have width of full screen underneath the A.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/left_part"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.3" />
   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/right_part"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.7" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The part A, and B are holders for different fragments, which has it's adapetr with cursor etc. and could have a few stacked up in backstack. So when rotate would prefer to not re start the activity so that the context is maintained, but just some how to rearrange the layout dynamically.

Not sure if it is doable. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: A clever use of [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) coupled with locking the application orientation in the AndroidManifest whilst providing your own transitions and animations might get you close.  However, Android is designed to handle rotation through the Activity Lifecycle.  It would take an incredible amount of overhead to gain what would be in the end "unnecessarily fancy animations".  Not worth it IMHO.

Comment: Thanks CzarMatt! I'm not even look at the animation here. Maybe for this case change the root to be relativeLayout and dynamically changing from side by side to all left aligned and with A showing on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it should work with dynamically changing the layout, tried following shows the expected behavior. 
Please comment if seeing any issue with this approach or having better solution. Thanks!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  

    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/right_pane"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_part" />


  <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/left_part"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/left_part_width"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>


void doChangeMode() {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftLp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) leftPart.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightLp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rightPart.getLayoutParams();

    if (mode == mode_side_by_side) {
        mode = mode_overlap;
        rightLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    } else {
        mode = mode_side_by_side;
        rightLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);

        //api 17 above
        //rightLp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    }
    Handler delayHandler = new Handler();
    delayHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rootView.requestLayout();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: Thanks Vladmir! Yes it has to be handled by self, the question is how to change the layout dynamically from left/right to up/bottom without loss the content they hold.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should be using [saved instance state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) to persist the data from the old layout and [restore it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) into the new layout.

It's theoretically possible to define a single layout that has sub groups from the different orientations, populate them both, then show / hide those as the rotation occurs using the method mentioned above for handling it yourself, but you are better off sticking Android's stock mechanism to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery! Load two sets of fragment is not a solution. Yes all the individual fragment are handling save restore instance state. but that is triggered by re-start activity. Would prefer to have a solution to avoid reload those data. Just hope dynamically rearrange layout could help.

Comment: FWIW, we'd actually implemented such a thing ourselves. It's fraught with edge cases that don't work and unexpected behavior. It's not recommended. There's a reason why Android implemented it the way they did, and it's not just to make your life harder.